# Display outerHTML of multiple elements when the element is created by user

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript program that will create an element each time a button is pressed. 
I use:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "hi"; 
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

I want to make it so when a user creates an element by clicking the button, then it will generate the element's html code or the outerHTML. But I also want it to do this if the user clicked the first button multiple times. So that means that I want it to generate the outer html for every element they make when they push the button. For this, I use:

```
    function CreateElement() { 

         var element = document.createElement("div");
         element.innerHTML = "hi"; 
         document.body.appendChild(element);

         var code = element.outerHTML;

    }
```

However, the problem is that there are multiple elements that were created that were under the variable "element". So I want the, "code" variable to contain the outerHTML of all of the elements. I've tried:

```
function createElement() { 

         var code = element.outerHTML;
         code = code + element.outerHTML  //will add the outer html to the variable each time a new element is created

    }
```

...but it always just replaces the whole variable instead of adding the outerhtml to the variable each time the button is clicked to make an element. My goal is to make the variable "code" look something like `"<div>hi</div> <div>hi</div>"`  (as a string)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append each dynamic element into a single container, then take that container's `innerHTML`:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function createElement() {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.textContent= "hi";
  container.appendChild(element);
  console.log(container.innerHTML);

}
button.onclick = createElement;
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Also, just a suggestion regarding `element.innerHTML = "hi";` - best to only use `innerHTML` when deliberately setting or retrieving *HTML markup*. If you just have text, it's faster, safer, and more appropriate to use `.textContent`.